# Post empty body (string having length of 0)

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

To post something to the server I use this code:

```js
var u1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
u1.open('POST', 'java/packagename');
u1.send(''); // <- string length of 0, a valid packagename in java.

var u2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
u2.open('POST', 'java/packagename');
u2.send('a'); // <- string length of 1, also a valid package name in java.
```

Unfortunately the string of length 0 is not posted.

Comment: Because if you're sending an empty string, then you're sending nothing.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen I disagree. Null or undefined is nothing, a empty string is a empty string.

Comment: Right, but that's not how http works. In reality when you send a network request, there is no such thing as a data type, it's all strings, the headers, everything. So therefore any server will interpret an "empty" string as nothing, because you're sending... nothing.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Read the spec mate, a empty line seperates the header from the body. The empty line is a indication for "there is a body to send". If no empty line is sent there is not even a empty string sent.

Comment: You're not sending a line, you're sending an empty string, aka nothing. If you want to send a line, then use a new line character like `\n`

Comment: So consider how that line separator would be created.... `if(data)` and empty string is falsey

Comment: @SebastianOlsen The empty line must be sent by the browser. After that empty line there must be sent nothing. But at the moment there even is not sent the empty line, indicating that there is no body. See this image: https://edwin.baculsoft.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/json.png

Comment: I am not sure what your image is supposed to prove, because in your image you're not sending an empty string, you're sending JSON.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen Its not my picture, but a presentation of the empty line specified in RFC2616 because you hardly do not like to read the specs.

Comment: Again, empty line and empty string are two different things. If you want to send an empty line, use a control character like `\n`

Comment: @SebastianOlsen You still get me wrong. I do not like to send a empty line, the browser is sending a empty line if there is a body to post (even if the body is of length 0).

Comment: Okay, I think a better question is, why do you want to achieve this? Even if it were as you are saying, why is it important?

Comment: @SebastianOlsen That a thousand times better question :D. Its written in the question.

Comment: I still don't understand. If you just want to send a post request without a body, then, surely you can just do `u1.send()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by myself.

I rewrote the u1-code to

```
var h = value === null?'null':(v === ''?'empty-string':(v === undefined?'undefined':null));
if (h != null) {
    u1.setRequestHeader('X-empty-body-interpret-as', h);
}
```

(I know what all of you think: Hey you violate against RFC 6648 but I do not care at the moment)

In the controller I read the header like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="java/packagename", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> updatePackage(@RequestBody(required=false) String entityPackageNew, HttpServletRequest request) {
    String interpretNullAs = request.getHeader("X-empty-body-interpret-as");
    DP databaseMavenRevelation = entityManager.find(DP.class, databaseMavenRevelationId);
    if (entityPackageNew == null) {
        switch (interpretNullAs) {
            case "empty-string":
                databaseMavenRevelation.setEntityPackage("");
                break;
            case "null":
            case "undefined":
                databaseMavenRevelation.setEntityPackage(null);
                break;
        }
    } else { 
        databaseMavenRevelation.setEntityPackage(entityPackageNew);
    }
    entityManager.persist(databaseMavenRevelation);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: This does not work for Byte-bodys, they always get 0.